# Считывание чисел и знаков и вывод результата

Tags: java, массивы

Вводим в консоль произвольное к-во чисел и знаков оператора (поочередно). С каждым шагом вычитаем результат. Пример: вводим в консоль `4+4*1*6+7*2+4+5+8+3*2` - выводим результат. Результат состоит по принципу ввода в калькулятор, то есть `4+4 = 8*1 = 8*6 = 48+7 = 55....` и т.д.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(sc.next());
}
```

Считать получилось, а вот как его теперь сложить/перемножить, сообразить не могу. Засунуть в массив чаров? - размер заранее неизвестен да и как дальше, что с ним можно сделать?
Буду благодарен за любую идею.

Comment: Введенные данные, можете поэлементно добавлять в `ArrayList<String>`, а затем, обработав его, получить результат.

Comment: Или просто в строку например, а потом производить операции перебирая элементы строки

Answer (score 3):

Вот реализация «*в лоб*», которая весьма проста для понимания (здесь предполагается, что исходные данные – корректны):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args)  {
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        arrayList.add("5");
        arrayList.add("+");
        arrayList.add("6");
        arrayList.add("-");
        arrayList.add("7");
        arrayList.add("/");
        arrayList.add("5");
        arrayList.add("*");
        arrayList.add("3");
        arrayList.add("+");
        arrayList.add("3");
        arrayList.add("-");
        arrayList.add("19");
        System.out.println(calc(arrayList));
    }

    public static double calc(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        double result = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(0));
        double number;
        String action = arrayList.get(1);

        for (int i=2; i<arrayList.size(); i++) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                action = arrayList.get(i);
            } else {
                number = Double.parseDouble(arrayList.get(i));
                switch (action) {
                    case "+":
                        result += number;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result -= number;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result *= number;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        result /= number;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно разбить на отдельные операторы, для этого нужен lexer, который разбивает строку на токены. Подробнее [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792737/splitting-input-string-for-a-calculator).

Когда разделишь, основная работа будет сделана, т.к. за каждым числом уже будет стоять оператор в массиве, а за оператором опять число. Единственный ньюанс, если хочешь со скобочками, тогда возможно такое, что будет несколько операторов подряд, например 5,*,(,5,+,5,) и т.д. Это нужно учесть.